# 401 response doesn't return json

Tags: javascript, php, json, http-headers, phalcon

This is my api using phalcon:

```
$response = new Response();
$response->setStatusCode( 401, 'Unauthorized' );
$response->setContentType( 'application/json', 'UTF-8' );
$response->setJsonContent( ['status' => 401] );
$response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',  '*');
$response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Authorization');
$response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
return $response;
```

And this is my request using Mithril framework:

```
options = {method: 'GET', url: "http://.../flights/recent"};
var oldConfig = options.config || function() {};

options.config = function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthComponent.token());
    oldConfig(xhr);
};

var deferred = m.deferred();

m.request(options).then(deferred.resolve, function(error) {
    if(error.status === 401) {
        AuthComponent.originalRoute = m.route();
        m.route('/login');
    }
});

return deferred.promise;
```

That api code is obviously just a test, not the final code. It is supposed to simulate an expired token where it responds to a request with a 401 header and a json `status=401` so it can be read in JS `error.status`.

The `m.request` knows it's an error but `error` variable returns `null`.

On Google Chrome developer tools the request shows 401 Unauthorized but the Response tab shows "This request has no response data available.".

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `send()` the response.

```
$response = new \Phalcon\Http\Response();
$response->setStatusCode( 401, 'Unauthorized' );
$response->setContentType( 'application/json', 'UTF-8' );
$response->setJsonContent( ['status' => 401] );
$response->send();
```

You should check this tutorial: https://docs.phalconphp.com/pt/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html

Comment: That code was inside a function, it was sending the response outside of it. Solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749662/cant-get-401-response-body