# Can't get 401 response body

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-headers

I managed to get JSON content using `jQuery.ajax()`. Currently, it fetches the content from another host containing a single index.php file returning a 401 response with the following body: `{'status':401}`.

This is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://restapi',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() { document.write('works'); },
        error: function(xhr) { document.write('failed, status:' + xhr.status); },
        beforeSend: setHeader
    });
});

function setHeader(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer 12345');
}
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Authorization");

header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");

echo json_encode(['status' => 401]);

exit;
```

If I remove the header, `xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer 12345');`, everything works fine (the response has a json body and `xhr.status` returns `401`). But with the Authorization header the body returns nothing and `xhr.status` returns `0`.

I need to send the auth token in that header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the same thing using Node.js and noticed it sent two requests/responses. One with a 204 header and another with the intended 401 and the json body. First method was OPTIONS and second method was GET, so I tried it with this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    header("HTTP/1.1 204 No Content");
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
    echo json_encode(['status' => 401]);
}
```

Works fine.